# Idiom that means "to understand a story better by listening to it from the beginning?"

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests

Example:

> "I think I should I start my story from the beginning. That way you
>   can [...].

Is there any idiom for that? Preferably idioms that evoke something physical, imagery.

Comment: _take it from the top_? This is more commonly used for music than stories, though.

Comment: take a step back?

Answer (score 1):

I think that "to start a story at the beginning" is fairly idiomatic; it's certainly a familiar construct.

For something slightly more dynamic, you could emulate Lewis Carroll and use "Begin at the beginning."